# How to disable TSLint Warning - deep imports

Tags: typescript, import, compiler-errors, angular-cli, tslint

I am getting this **warning** when compiling an angular universal app:

> Warning: Entry point 'my-module' contains deep imports into
>   '/src/app/mocks/myModule.ts'. This is probably not a problem, but may
>   cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

I have a paths change in tsconfig, which works and is my desired functionality. I would like to be able to *disable* this particular warning.  I assume there is some change I can make to **tslint.json** to allow deep imports all together, or to allow it in this particular case.

ESlint seems to have **nx-enforce-module-boundaries**, but I don't think that is applicable to me since this project uses TSLint. However, I tried it anyway with no success:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "nx-enforce-module-boundaries": [
      true,
      {
        "allow": [
          ["/src/app/mocks/myModule.ts"]
        ]
      }
    ],
    ...
```

I can't find anything in [TSLint Rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) that seem to help me. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't relevant to Nx as this warning is coming from the Angular CLI (and possibly webpack). It's also not coming from TSLint, so changing that config won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a custom webpack, as I could not figure out how to disable to warning.  Webpack has no deep-import warnings:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^myModule$/, path.join(__dirname, './src/app/mocks/myModule.mock.server.ts')),
    ]
}
```

https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack